# SoftwareContext and QML Camera

Tags: qt, qml

I've compiled Qt 5.9 for a board with no hardware acceleration and we don't want to use X11. Using `linuxfb` QML works fine after setting these environment variables.

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0
QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
```

Now, I want to use the camera / mediaplayer. Initialising the Camera and `VideoOutput` QML components but nothing shows up on the screen although `GStreamer` claims frames are being generated (GST_DEBUG=4). Is there any environment variable needed for setting up the video surface needed by the GStreamer? Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Hi, I can suggest to use _mesa_ which supports software rendering.

Comment: Hi, linuxfb does not support OpenGL and currently no abilities to show video in qml, and eglfs could be used instead.